# Why the calculation of a floating point requires lots of battery power?

Tags: android, mobile, floating-point

I was reading this great article talking about how to build more efficient Android apps:http://blog.azoft.com/android-application-development-tips/.

Those tips are really helpful. But I don't quite understand this one:

"**Since the calculation of a floating point requires lots of battery power**, you might consider using microdegrees for bulk geo math and caching values when performing DPI tasks with DisplayMetrics."

Why calculating a floating point requires lots of battery power please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lots" is a bit of a hyperbole.  If you are doing multiple seconds of floating point calculation, it will be more battery-intensive than the equivalent integer math, but the occasional multiply won't hurt.  Unless you know you have math heavy operations, I wouldn't worry about it.  To put a number to it, you are looking at ~1 mAh per billion operations (typical).

As for why, most integer operations execute in fewer than 4 cycles, while single precision floating point division can hit 96 cycles.  Further, in some cases, a floating-point coprocessor may be used, which will draw additional power since it may be shut down when not in use to save battery.

See the [ARM9 Instruction Cycle Count Summary](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0165b/I1028171.html) for details.